# How do I save an image captured from Unity app to iOS Photos?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a script written in C# that takes a screenshot on button click.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class screenshotButton : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void takeScreenshot()
    {
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
        Debug.Log(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"));
    }

}
```

My problem is that once the screenshot is captured on an iPhone, the photo is not saved to the photo gallery. When testing on my laptop, the image is saved in the folder above the Assets folder. Any help would be appreciated so that this function works on iPhone and allows users to see their saved screenshots in the photo gallery. Thanks!

(P.S. I am aware of how to take a screenshot normally on an iOS device. I am wanting this screenshot function to work as a button in app. Thanks!)

Comment: There no lines in your code for saving a screenshot.

Comment: At least on desktop, ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot() handles the saving. When I press the button that this function is assigned to on desktop the image is saved above the Assets folder. I think it just has trouble accessing the photos on iOS.

Comment: Have you read the [description](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html): **On mobile platforms the filename is appended to the persistent data path.**

Answer (score 0):

You can read Application.persistentDataPath in Unity.doc
[Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

Windows Store Apps: Application.persistentDataPath points to

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<productname>\LocalState
```

iOS: Application.persistentDataPath points to

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<guid>/Documents.
```

Android: Application.persistentDataPath points to

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files
```

on most devices (some older phones might point to location on SD card if present), the path is resolved using `android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir`.